# for loop does not execute correctly in C

Tags: c, for-loop

The for loop in the following function does not seem to store correctly. The value that returns for `range_angle` is the very first value, which I know is not correct. Also, my `compute_landing_distance` function (not shown here) works just fine, so it must be something in the for loop:

```
for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83;.01)
{
    x_f = compute_landing_distance(v0,theta_l_deg);

    if (x_f > range_distance)
    {
        range_distance = x_f;
        range_angle = theta_l_deg;
    }

    else
    {
    break;
    }
}

return range_angle;
```

I want this loop to run from `theta_l_deg` = `22.5` to `83` in increments of `.01`, and return the largest value for `range_angle` in that range. Also, I am aware that C only calculates in radians, and the `compute_landing_distance` function takes that into account.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ and notice that `0.01` is *not* exactly representable as IEEE754

Comment: what do you think `for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83;.01)` line do? specially the `;.01)` part?

Comment: Don't blame the compiler or the implementation at first. Question first and above all your own code. Your `for` loop *is* running "correctly" (as you asked it to), but *you* (not the computer) made a mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong for loop, missing increment

```
for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83;.01)
```

should be

```
for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83; theta_l_deg += .01)
```

Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ and notice that `0.01` is *not* exactly representable as IEEE754

BTW, you should compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Answer (score 4):

```
for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83;.01)
```

should be

```
for ( theta_l_deg = 22.5 ; theta_l_deg <= 83 ; theta_l_deg += 0.01 )
```

In your original code, you are not incrementing the value of `theta_l_deg`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (theta_l_deg=22.5; theta_l_deg<=83; theta_l_deg+=0.01)
{
    x_f = compute_landing_distance(v0,theta_l_deg);

    if (x_f > range_distance)
    {
        range_distance = x_f;
        range_angle = theta_l_deg;
    }

    else
    {
    break;
    }
}

return range_angle;
```

Comment: A code only answer which does not even specify what was wrong with the original code is not very good.